# Javascript works in debugger when breakpoint is hit, but not without it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

After losing focus, I check whether the textbox value is within the acceptable range, and if not, alert the user, then switch focus back to the textbox. This works as intended when I hit a breakpoint in the Javascript, or even when it is done in code-behind. It seems ignored completely when running without developer tools or with no breakpoints.

First, I make it so the textbox can handle the `blur` event when the page loads:

```vb
Weight.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CheckForRouteInfoChanges();")
Weight.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ValidateWeight();")
```

The control itself is like this:

```html
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Weight" Width="150px" />
```

Finally, this is the Javascript function:

```js
function ValidateWeight() {
    var currentWeight = document.getElementById("<%=Weight.ClientID%>");
    if (currentWeight.value != document.getElementById("<%=oldWeight.ClientID %>").value) {
        var valid = true;
        var current = parseInt(currentWeight.value);
        var minimum = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=MinWeight.ClientID%>").value);
        var maximum = parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=MaxWeight.ClientID%>").value);
        if (minimum > current) {
            alert("Weight must be at least " + minimum);
            console.log(currentWeight.value);
            valid = false;
        }
        if (maximum < current) {
            alert("Weight must be at most " + maximum);
            valid = false;
        }
        console.log('Finished checking weights!');
        if (!valid) {
            console.log(currentWeight.value);
            currentWeight.focus();
            currentWeight.select();
            console.log('Focus ought to be set!');
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea what else to check to see why it works only when I'm looking at it. I appreciate any help with this.

**EDIT** Based on the comment by iamdlm, I added some console logging. Unfortunately, the console output is as I expect, but the focus isn't:

```text
3
Finished checking weights!
3
Focus ought to be set!
```

Comment: No error messages in browser console without breakpoints? That behavior usually happens because of asynchronous operations and/or DOM loading. Try logging `currentWeight.value`, `oldWeight.value`, `minimum`, `maximum`, etc. to the console to see if their values are what you expect when the code runs without breakpoints.

Comment: I didn't know about logging to the Javascript console, but figured it out from your suggestion. Unfortunately, all of the values are exactly what I expect. I'll edit my post to include some extra console lines which seem to indicate everything is working as intended, but the display still isn't right.

Comment: I just figured out how to add an Event Listener breakpoint, and breaking on Blur works correctly after the break, simply continuing. No break still leaves the focus where it would be otherwise. No break logs as expected with no change in focus from the code.